# argument "x" is missing, with no default in ezANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I am getting a weird problem with ezANOVA. When I try to execute code below it says that some data is missing, but when I look at the data, nothing is missing.

```r
model_acc <- ezANOVA(data = nback_acc_summary[complete.cases(nback_acc_summary),],
                     dv = Stimulus1.ACC,
                     wid = Subject,
                     within = c(ExperimentName, Target),
                     between = Group,
                     type = 3,
                     detailed = T)
```

When I run these lines I get an error message that says:

```
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```

Then I run

```
ezDesign(nback_acc_summary)
```

And get the message:

```
Error in as.list(c(x, y, row, col)) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I am not sure what to change in the code, because I can't really figure out what the problem is. I've researched the issue online, and it seems like quite a lot of users have encountered it before, but there is a very limited amount of solutions posted. I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For an ANOVA model you must have observations in all conditions created by the design of your model.

For example, if ExperimentName, Target, and Group each have two levels each, you have 2 x 2 x 2 = 8 conditions which require multiple observations in each condition. Then, add a constraint to this that your model is repeated measures which means that each Subject within a level of your between factor Group must have observations for all of the within conditions (i.e., ExperimentName x Target = 2 x 2 = 4).

The first error suggests you have fallen short of having enough data in the conditions suggested by your model.

The following should produce a plot to help identify which conditions are missing data:

```
ezDesign(
  data = nback_acc_summary[complete.cases(nback_acc_summary), ], 
  x = Target, 
  y = Subject, 
  row = ExperimentName, 
  col = Group
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matthew! According to the plot I am indeed missing data. Do you have any suggestions on what the best way to deal with it is? I thought the ```complete.cases``` would deal with this problem, but apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: The issue is not that you are missing data and should remove other data related to the missing data. The issue is that you have missing data as a result of not having observed cells in your ANOVA design. `complete.cases()` will only remove incomplete rows in the data frame. The command does not know anything about the groups in your ANOVA model.

Comment: The best solution would be to collect data where you are missing it, but that is probably not an option. Another approach may be to explore what a linear mixed model using something like `lme4::lmer()` can do. At this point you will be better served to post your new questions on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).